# R preprocessing error: Error in predict.BoxCoxTrans(bc[[i]], x[, i]) : newdata should be a numeric vector

Tags: machine-learning, transformation, data-preprocessing

xtestdata is an R data frame. It contains solely numeric data. There is no missing data.

```
ncol(xtestdata) # 45
nrow(xtestdata) # 325
# str(xtestdata)  all numeric
```

I seek to preprocess the data. This code for preprocessing of data yields an error:

```
testtrans <- preProcess(xtestdata, method = c("BoxCox", "center", "scale"))
```

The error is:

```
Error in predict.BoxCoxTrans(bc[[i]], x[, i]) : 
  newdata should be a numeric vector
```

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

The data set named xtestdata was a tibble.

When I got it out of tibble mode, all was well with the preProcess command.

To "un-tibble" a data set, do this:

xtestdata <- as.data.frame(xtestdata)